# Should you read back the QNH from an ATIS broadcast?

Tags: air-traffic-control, caa-uk-regulations

A typical ATIS broadcast includes the QNH ("altimeter" for the cousins).

My habit is to read this back since I have effectively been given the setting by ATC and it is required for my startup. For example:

> Finden 37 with information Delta, the QNH 1022.

I can't find any reference on whether this is required or not.  Additionally, do any CPLs or ATCOs on here consider this to be good or bad practice?

If someone wants me to tag with a jurisdiction, then it would be UK CAA since that is where I fly but I am interested in all responses.

Comment: Typically here in the US you just say "With Delta" and ATC assumes you have copied (and understand) all the ATIS information. Sometimes ATC will give an updated wind between ATIS, but the baro usually doesn't change that fast (hourly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uk CAA CAP493 Section 3 Chapter 1 Paragraph 11.4 states :

> In the case of a departure ATIS, controllers must obtain a read-back of all relevant altimeter settings contained in the broadcast, unless the setting will also be passed in association with start-up or taxi clearance.

So from the point of view of the controller you are doing a good thing because you are saving him the expense of having to confirm that you have the right QNH on board.

Answer (score 0):

ICAO Doc 4444 Section 4.5.7.5.1 states:

> The flight crew shall read back to the air traffic
>   controller safety-related parts of ATC clearances and instructions
>   which are transmitted by voice. The following items shall
>   always be read back:
>   ...
>
> c) runway-in-use, altimeter settings, SSR codes, level
>   instructions, heading and speed instructions and,
>   *whether issued by the controller or contained in automatic
>   terminal information service (ATIS) broadcasts*,
>   transition levels.

Comment: Can you link to this document? What is the jurisdiction?

Comment: google icao doc 4444. In uk the corresponding document should be CAP493 .

Comment: I think you mean section 4.5.7.5.1(c)...

Comment: By the way, it looks like the 4444 is a document for ATC controllers, not pilots. It says the controller must read back the setting, and the section you are quoting is about en-route flight levels.

Comment: I think flight crew is meant to be understood as pilots. I was pointing you to pararaph c) " runway-in-use, altimeter settings, SSR codes, level instructions, heading and speed instructions and, whether issued by the controller or contained in auto- matic terminal information service (ATIS) broadcasts, transition levels."

Comment: @RonBeyer  That document does require a readback of altimeter settings obtained from ATIS.

Comment: @Simon I am inclined to disagree. A plain reading of the text would indicate that only *transition levels* broadcast by ATIS need be readback, not altimeter settings.